# MySQL modify each item in JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-json

Consider a MySQL table `t1` containing a column `max_ages` of `JSON` type:

| id | max_ages (JSON) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [3, 5, 12] |
| 2 | [7] |
| 3 | [10, 10, 16, 17] |

Now I need to select `max_ages` and modify each item by adding one, something like this *(I'll use JavaScript to demonstrate what I need)*:

`SELECT id, max_ages.map( (max_age) => max_age + 1 ) from t1;`

So the expected result would be:

| id | max_ages |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [4, 6, 13] |
| 2 | [8] |
| 3 | [11, 11, 17, 18] |

It there a `JSON_*` function, or other way to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: I think the easiest way will involve using `JSON_TABLE()` to split the array into rows, then `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to combine the results back into an array.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to store these values in a JSON array if you want to use them as if they are discrete data elements?

Comment: @BillKarwin we are team working on big app, last months experimenting with JSON data type. In this case my colleague decided to store values as inclusive while I need them dump exclusive.. just real life stories..